Cannnot open Rnw file after R update to 4.4.0 - (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading `count`)
I recently upgraded to R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt) and also updated the R version in RStudio via the global options.
Since the update, I am unable to open Rnw (RSweave) files. When attempting to do so, I encounter the following error message:

So far, I have tried installing and updating all the relevant packages such as

install.packages("knitr")
install.packages("rmarkdown")
tinytex::reinstall_tinytex() tinytex::tlmgr_install("listings")
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)

but still couldn't fix the issue.
I googled it further, and I found this Github Issue related to "storybook"(https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/23787), but I am not sure if this is relevant to my case.
Could I get some insights on how to solve this issue?

What version of RStudio are you using? Can you create a new Rnw file in RStudio? Are you prevented from opening them all, or only one particular file?

@MrFlick Thank you for asking! I am using the most recent version of the RStudio. I can create a new Rnw files, but I cannot open any Rnw files. I could open the exact same Rnw files in RStudio on a different computer, but not on my PC.

@MrFlick Removing and reinstalling R and RStudio did not resolve the issue. However, I discovered that the same error message appears when I use curly braces, { and }, in a code chunk within a newly created Rnw file. I suppose the curly braces might be the source of the problem.

I had the same issue with an older version of R, so it is definitely an RStudio problem.
I installed the previous version from here:
https://docs.posit.co/previous-versions/rstudio/
I am sure there will be a patch quite soon and you can upgrade again to the newest version of RStudio.

You are right! After downgrading the RStudio to 2023.12.1 version, I can open the Rnw files again. Thank you very much!!!

@jjmerelo you can follow the issue here: link

I was able to take the .tex file of a .rnw (that didn't inclcude any R code), and copy/paste that into a new file, delete the extras that were added by Sweave, and it ran. Did not work very well for a file that had code chunks though.
